# PHP Session variables with if/else

Tags: php, session

For some reason, I'm having an issue setting a session variable and using an if/else to see if the value equals something specific. Here's the relevant code:

```
function ask_name(){
     return "What is your name?\n\n";   
     $_SESSION['status'] = "name";
}

if (!isset($_SESSION["name"])||!isset($_SESSION['status'])) {
  $message = ask_name();
} 
elseif ($_SESSION["status"]==="name"){
$message = hello_name();
}
else{
    $message = respond_to_answer();
}
```

I know that `$_SESSION["name"]` is definitely set, but I can't get my `if/elseif/else` to move to the `elseif`because it's not getting that `$_SESSION['status']` is not set.

What am I missing here?

Comment: try `&&` instead of `||` i.e., `if ((!isset($_SESSION["name"]))&&(!isset($_SESSION['status']))) {`

Comment: Read up on "return" http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yep...that was the issue. I just totally missed reordering those when I did some copy and pasting.

Comment: No worries; I've been victim of that *"once"* ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function ask_name(){
     return "What is your name?\n\n";   
     $_SESSION['status'] = "name";
}
```

`return` exits the current function and returns to the callee, this means that your `$_SESSION['status'] = "name";` code is never ran, switch it :

```
function ask_name(){
     $_SESSION['status'] = "name";
     return "What is your name?\n\n";   
}
```

Comment: Ugh...that was it. Can't believe I missed that. I'll accept when I'm able. Appreciate the help.